# How can I show hidden text when keyboard user is focused on element

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I have a card that has some hidden text. For accessibility purposes, I need that hidden text to be shown when you are focused on the card (right now it only works when hovered).

What is the easiest/ best way to do this so that the card is accessible to keyboard users?

I attached an image showing that the card can be focused on. and I also attaached an image of the hidden text that is shown on hover. Is there any other info you would you need to help me? Unfortunately I can't share the url to the site. But here is the html for that card. The paragraph is hidden by using opacity 0 and a transform property

```
<article id="brxe-fbcf6d" class="brxe-div suba-priority-card">
    <div class="brxe-div suba-priority-card__body">
      <h3 class="brxe-heading fr-article-card-foxtrot__title">
        <a href="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/our-people/employee-resource-groups/#erg-blends">BLENDS</a>
        text
      </h3>
      <div class="brxe-text-basic fr-article-card-foxtrot__paragraph">
        The Black &amp; Latino Employee Network for Diversity at xxxx(BLENDS) mission is to empower Black 
        and Latino employees by creating professional development programs, offering educational resources, 
        and engaging with the community in diversity initiatives.
      </div>
      
      <footer class="brxe-div suba-priority-card__footer">
        <a href="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/our-people/employee-resource-groups#erg-blends" aria-label="Read more about BLENDS" class="brxe-div suba-priority-card__info">
          <time class="brxe-text-basic suba-priority-card__read-more" datetime="June 7, 2023">Read more</time>
          <i class="brxe-icon suba-priority-card__cta-icon fas fa-arrow-right-long" aria-label="arrow"></i>
        </a>
      </footer>
    </div>
    
    <div class="brxe-div suba-priority-card__image-wrapper">
      <picture class="brxe-image suba-priority-card__image css-filter size-full" decoding="async">
        <source type="image/webp" data-srcset="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/Group-2030.jpg.webp" srcset="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/Group-2030.jpg.webp">
        <img width="700" height="490" src="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/Group-2030.jpg" alt="Fingerprint image" decoding="async" class="perfmatters-lazy entered pmloaded" data-src="https://ourimpact.xxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/Group-2030.jpg" data-ll-status="loaded">
        <noscript>
          <img width="700" height="490" src="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/Group-2030.jpg" alt="Fingerprint image" decoding="async"/>
        </noscript>
      </picture>
    </div>
</article>
```

I don't know where to start

Comment: `selector:focus` will match when keyboard is focused on an the element matching the selector.

Comment: thank you for your response. so where do I add the focus? to the heading and the read more class?

Comment: In the CSS.  Something like `.classname:focus { opacity: 1; }`

Comment: but the paragraph never gets focused (because it is hidden)--- its the heading and button link that get focused on when using tab.

Comment: How do you do it with `:hover`?

Comment: @AndrewMcSpadden Do you want to show it when ```Read more``` is being clicked?

Comment: No, I want it to show when the heading or read more is focused. When you click the card it goes to a different page.

Right now when you hover the body of the card, it will show the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I demonstrated how you can use the selectors on both cases and also used some dummy text content to show how focus is working as the actual text is not available.

In your case, where you will be using it might be somewhat different. So you need to understand how `:has()` selector works and change it accordingly.

```css
/* Heading focus selector */
#brxe-fbcf6d .suba-priority-card__body h3:has(a:focus) + div span{
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

/* Read more focus selector */
#brxe-fbcf6d div:has(footer.suba-priority-card__footer a:focus) span{
  opacity: 1 !important;   
}
```

```html
<article id="brxe-fbcf6d" class="brxe-div suba-priority-card">
  <div class="brxe-div suba-priority-card__body">
    <h3 class="brxe-heading fr-article-card-foxtrot__title">
      <a href="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/our-people/employee-resource-groups/#erg-blends">BLENDS</a>
      text
    </h3>
    <div class="brxe-text-basic fr-article-card-foxtrot__paragraph">
      The Black &amp; Latino Employee Network for Diversity at xxxx(BLENDS) mission is to empower Black 
      and Latino employees by creating professional development programs, offering educational resources, 
      and engaging with the community in diversity initiatives.

      <span style="color: green; opacity: 0;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut cum quibusdam aliquid eum veniam vitae, dolor labore tempore saepe veritatis laboriosam nulla vero quae unde officiis nemo nesciunt ex officia!
      </span>
    </div>

    <footer class="brxe-div suba-priority-card__footer">
      <a href="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/our-people/employee-resource-groups#erg-blends" aria-label="Read more about BLENDS" class="brxe-div suba-priority-card__info">
        <time class="brxe-text-basic suba-priority-card__read-more" datetime="June 7, 2023">Read more</time>
        <i class="brxe-icon suba-priority-card__cta-icon fas fa-arrow-right-long" aria-label="arrow"></i>
      </a>
    </footer>
  </div>

  <div class="brxe-div suba-priority-card__image-wrapper">
    <picture class="brxe-image suba-priority-card__image css-filter size-full" decoding="async">
      <source type="image/webp" data-srcset="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/Group-2030.jpg.webp" srcset="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/Group-2030.jpg.webp">
      <img width="700" height="490" src="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/Group-2030.jpg" alt="Fingerprint image" decoding="async" class="perfmatters-lazy entered pmloaded" data-src="https://ourimpact.xxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/Group-2030.jpg" data-ll-status="loaded">
      <noscript>
        <img width="700" height="490" src="https://ourimpact.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/Group-2030.jpg" alt="Fingerprint image" decoding="async"/>
      </noscript>
    </picture>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Interesting. I was worried that it might violate WCAG SC 1.4.13 https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/content-on-hover-or-focus but I tried your example with NVDA and Narrator, and, as long as the link remains focused, I can get the screen reader to announce the revealed text with the "virtual cursor". I'd recommend testing with a few more screen readers, particularly on iOS and Android - where I suspect things might not go quite so smoothly - i.e. how will you get the screen reader to move to the revealed text using a touch gesture without moving focus away from the link?

Comment: I think that's a question not for me but for the OP because I just provided him a solution to what he was asking. `What is the easiest/ best way to do this so that the card is accessible to keyboard users?` - OP